# Crop rectangle from image issue

Tags: android, ios, image, bitmap

I need to take picture from camera in landscape orientation (capture the full screen) with this mask:

[image]

Then crop rectangle from image like this:
[image]

I have some problem with cropping.
I do(android):

```
public Bitmap getCropImage() {

    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap();
    int captureBitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    int captureBitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

    // to get a multiplicative factor of axises.
    float xCoefficient = captureBitmapWidth / 720.0;
    float yCoefficient = captureBitmapHeight / 480.0;

    int cropRectangleWidth = 200;
    int cropRectangleHeight = 100;
    int cropRectangle_a_x = 200;
    int cropRectangle_a_y = 300;

    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,
            Math.round(cropRectangle_a_x * xCoefficient),
            Math.round(cropRectangle_a_y * yCoefficient),
            Math.round(cropRectangleWidth * xCoefficient),
            Math.round(cropRectangleHeight * yCoefficient));

    return bitmap;
}
```

iphone:

```
extension UIImage {
    func crop() -> UIImage {

        // to get a multiplicative factor of axises.
        let xCoefficient : CGFloat = self.size.width / RectangleConfig.WIDTH;
        let yCoefficient : CGFloat = self.size.height / RectangleConfig.HEIGTH;

        var cropRect = CGRectMake(RectangleConfig.x * xCoefficient,
                                  RectangleConfig.y * yCoefficient,
                                  RectangleConfig.cropRectWidth * xCoefficient,
                                  RectangleConfig.cropRectHeight * yCoefficient)

        cropRect.origin.x *= self.scale
        cropRect.origin.y *= self.scale
        cropRect.size.width *= self.scale
        cropRect.size.height *= self.scale

        let imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.CGImage, cropRect)
        let image = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef!, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)

        return image
    }
}
```

On some mobile devices, I get the correct result, on other the crop rectangle shifted down and to the left. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the problem with your code is that you always use 720x480, which is always the case with different android devices.

Maybe more like:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

float xCoefficient = captureBitmapWidth / metrics.widthPixels;
float yCoefficient = captureBitmapHeight / metrics.heightPixels;
```